# Proving an idempotent binary operation where $(x\ast y)\ast z=(y\ast z)\ast x$ is commutative

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

Let $S$ be a set and $\ast$  be a binary operation on $S$ satisfying

1) $x\ast x=x$ for all $x\in S$,

2) $(x\ast y)\ast z=(y\ast z)\ast x$ for all $x,y,z \in S$.

Show that $x\ast y=y\ast x$.

I haven't got any idea for solving this problem.

Comment: Do we know if $\ast$ must be associative?  If so, note that $(x\ast y)=(x\ast y)\ast (x\ast y)$ and use property $2$ on that.

Comment: @JMoravitz No need to *assume* associativity, that follows from condition 2 after we prove commutativity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(xy)x=(yx)x=(xx)y=xy$$
$$xy=(xy)(xy)=(y(xy))x=((xy)x)y=(xy)y=(yy)x=yx$$